# Appveyor dotnet publish failing using net core 1.0.0

Tags: .net-core, appveyor

I have the current configuration for appveyor

```html
version: 0.0.{build}

before_build:
 - nuget restore mysolution.sln
 - cmd: set BUILD_VERSION=%APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER%

configuration: Release
 
build:
 project: myproject.xproj

after_build:
 - dotnet publish myproject --framework netcoreapp1.0 --output %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%\out --configuration Release
 - 7z a %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%\package-net-core.zip  %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%\out\*
```

Until yesterday it was working fine. But for some reason after building today I see this error:

```html
C:\projects\myproject.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, net core "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/6318/r?go=aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL2FwcHZleW9yL2NpL2lzc3Vlcy8xMzc3I2lzc3VlY29tbWVudC0yODc2NDQyNzE=).

After copying `global.json` to root it worked.